How do I keep my tremolo strat in tune?
I know there are a lot of advanced tremolo set-up rigs. I'm just wondering, if there are some basic techniques while playing and such.

'While playing' - not really, apart from don't use it!. It's in the set up, and lubricating all parts that move against each other.

@Tim, have you noticed the comment box says "Avoid answering questions in comments"! If the comment is not helpful in any way, you could even consider not posting it!

@ojs - I didn't see that as a proper answer, hence, a comment. It wasn't complete enough.

@Tim I don't see it as a proper answer, either! The question is, why do you have to post it all! It's now on top of the page, where other, good answers should be!

Carl Verheyen has info online on how he sets up his Strat tremolo. In a nutshell, it involves adjusting the claw so there is more tension on the bass strings and less on the treble strings. He adjusts the claw on both sides until specific strings rise specific intervals when you pull the arm up as far as it will go. I did this on a Strat style guitar I have with good results. Below is his explanation and instructions from the Fender forum website. There is also this video of him with less technical info but an overall explanation of the concept: 


*For the last 20 years the Fender Stratocaster has been my main guitar. When working with the bridge setup I always strive for the most musical and in-tune mechanical operation I can find. I’ve asked hundreds of players about their setup and over the years I’ve come up with my own method that always returns to pitch and has many musical benefits as well. The method described works best when the tuners are working properly, the nut has been properly cut so string don’t bind, the neck truss rod properly adjusted and the six (or 2) mounting screws that fasten the bridge plate provide proper freedom of movement.
At the heart of the setup is balancing spring tension with string tension by adjusting the two long spring tension adjusting screws at the “claw” to which the tremolo springs are attached to the steel tremolo block. Use 3 springs from the tremolo block to the claw: furthest position left, furthest position right and center; do NOT set the outside springs at an angle.

Begin by adjusting the 2 screws of the claw so that when you pull UP on the tremolo arm and the bridge is in contact with the body the G string pulls up a minor 3rd. This will make the B string rise a whole step and the E string a half step. The mechanics of the system should first make musical sense. You will end up with an “Angled Claw” which is exactly what you’re looking for.
Next, adjust the screw on the bass side of the claw (closest to the low E string) so that when you pull up on the tremolo arm and the bridge is in contact with the body, the A and D string when fretted at the 5th fret (D and G) rise a whole step to E and A.
You may have to go back and forth a few times between the two adjusting screws until the bridge is stable and the intervals described are true. And you’ll need to correct the intonation by adjusting the bridge saddles.
When all is right and balanced between springs and strings, the Am7 barre chord on the 5th fret should sound like it is descending musically to an Abm7 when the bar is slightly depressed. It won't be perfect but it's a very musical sound you're after and should achieve. This effect is ideal for “shaking” chords and applying a manual tremolo to your voicings.
I use a Teflon lubricant (sold in electronic shops) under the strings at the nut slots and where the strings contact the string tree(s). You only need to use a little lube; wipe away any excess.
I try to use the minimum windings on the string posts, preferring just one if possible. My bass strings leave the post at the top; my trebles wind down and leave the post at the bottom.
There is a short video of me explaining the whole process at
VIDEO Carl Verheyen's Strat set-up 1.01 It was recorded a few years back in Amsterdam …….it may also help!
All the best,
Carl Verheyen"*


Let's start with the strings.
If you have mounted new guitar strings, it's important to stretch them and get them settled into tune before endeavoring a live performance.
The stretching can be done with a stretching tool, or by performing repeated bends and tugs on each string. Once properly stretched, quality strings can be expected to remain in tune.
Next, ponder how much pressure you put on the guitar's bridge during playing and palm-muting. (Some players put a lot of force into the bridge, and that can cause a lot of tuning instability.)
Same with excessive movements or motions that encourace neck bending.
YES, any guitar neck can and will bend or give a little during energetic performances. Just ask guitar player Adrian Belew.
Consider using some fine graphite powder on the nut and the bridge pieces, to help the strings glide (and not snag).
Onto the temperature.
If the guitar was stored in a chilly car, and then is placed onto a warm stage environment (or vice versa), a certain amount of tuning instability can be expected. Let your guitar rest on the stage long enough to come to room temperature, before you begin your set list.
Lastly, evaluate how much you use the Stratcaster's tremolo in the first place.
If you aren't a big fan of using the whammy bar, consider 'blocking' the trem.
This involves taking the back cover off, and inserting a wedge of wood or metal that prevents the tremolo springs and metal block from moving.
That's all I can think of for now.
Good luck with it!!

+1 for mentioning blocking the trem. Unless you particularly want the special effects of deep pitch drops, or the kind of vibrato you can only get from a trem, you're way better for tuning stability by turning it into a hardtail.
